# How make http request using form data by rest template?

Tags: spring, httprequest, recaptcha, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I can execute following http request using postman:
[image]
As you can see result:

```
{
    "succes":false
}
```

Now I need to execute same request using restTemplate.

To achieve it I have wrote following code:

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
 map.add("secret", "6Le8YwMTAAAAADTIDNBvjxg-x83jt5QvPN-dFGWs");
 map.add("response", recapchaResponse);

 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Map>(map, headers);
 restTemplate.exchange("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", HttpMethod.POST, entity,ReCaptchaResponse.class);
```

When I executes following code in debug I see following response:
[image]

As you can see response contains errors. Looks like `response` and `secret` is not received by server. why?

What do I wrong?

### P.S.

I have wrote analog using httpClient

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        postMethod.setParameter("secret", "6Le8YwMTAAAAADTIDNBvjxg-x83jt5QvPN-dFGWs");
        postMethod.setParameter("response", recapchaResponse);
        client.executeMethod(postMethod);
        String responseFromServer = new String(postMethod.getResponseBody());
```

It works good.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use [Unirest.io](http://unirest.io/java.html) from [Mashape](https://www.mashape.com/). It gives you the opportunity to simply create POST Request:

```
Unirest.post("http://link.to/rest").field("secret", "xxx").field("response", "xxx").asJsonAsync(new Callback<JsonNode>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse) {

        String response = httpResponse.getBody().toString();
        JSONObject responseDictionary = JSON.jsonToDictionary(response);     
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(UnirestException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() {

    }
});
```

This will create a POST Request to the given site and returns a JSON Object with the response in it.

> responseDictionary.get("success")

This will give you the needed boolean.

Comment: JSON - what the class?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that. I would also recommend to use Google's [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) toolkit in order to work with JSON Objects.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`RecaptchaResponse.java`:

```
public class RecaptchaResponse {

    public boolean success;

    @JsonProperty(value = "error-codes")
    public List<String> errorCodes;
}
```

in `LoginController.java`:

```
/* Spring's MultiValueMap, not Apache's */
MultiValueMap<String,String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String>();
params.add("secret", "...");
params.add("response", recaptchaValue);

RecaptchaResponse recaptchaResponse = restTemplate.postForObject("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", params, RecaptchaResponse.class);

if(recaptchaResponse.success)...
```